# How can I concatenate a single column of output into a list?

Tags: grep, ls, columns

I'm using:

```
ls /proc | grep -v "^[0-9].*"
```

to get a list of all the files and directories in /proc that don't begin with numbers.  The output is a single column list, i.e.:

```
acpi
asound
buddyinfo
bus
```

How can I make this a multi-column or item list, i.e.:

```
acpi asound buddyinfo bus
```

or

```
acpi,asound,buddyinfo,bus
```

I tried:

```
$ ls /proc | grep -v "^[0-9].*" | column -c5
```

but still got 1 column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `xargs`:

```
$ command ls /proc | grep -v "^[0-9].*" | xargs
```

The `command` part is necessary because if your `ls` is aliased to `ls --color` for example, it adds non-printing escape sequences to its output that `grep` somehow searches through and produces undesirable results.

---

**Other options**

If you don't mind your `PWD` changing:

```
$ cd /proc && echo [^0-9]*
```

If you don't want to change your `PWD`:

```
$ pushd . &>/dev/null && cd /proc && echo [^0-9]* && popd &>/dev/null
```

Or:

```
$ echo /proc/[^0-9]* | sed 's!/proc/!!g'
```

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Please see edited answer for an important point about using `ls`.

Comment: @terdon If your `ls` is aliased to `ls --color` try `ls /proc|grep --color ';'`

Comment: @terdon On my system (Debian Wheezy), I get things like: `[01;34mtty`!!

Comment: @terdon I'm using GNU `grep` 2.12

Comment: Do you need the `echo` after the `xargs`? On my system, `xargs` by itself produces the same output.

Answer (score 3):

#### One long list

*Using grep*

You could just use shell expansion on `/proc` and pipe it to `grep`:

```
$ echo /proc/* | grep -oP "(?<=/proc/)\D.*? " | paste -s -d ''
```

#### Example

```
$ echo /proc/* | grep -oP "(?<=/proc/)\D.*? " | paste -s -d ''
acpi asound buddyinfo bus cgroups ....
```

The above makes use of `grep`'s ability to use Perl's regular expression engine (PCRE). It's the `-P` switch to `grep`. The `-o` tells `grep` to only return the strings that match the pattern. We then make use of Perl's ability to lookbehinds. So when we find a string that beings with `/proc`, we then look after the `/proc` for any strings that do not start with a digit (`\D`). These are the strings that are return (the non-digit starting ones).

The paste does some cleanup for us by removing all the newline characters that the `grep` added when it starting displaying its results.

*Using sed*

An alternative to this method would be to use `sed` instead (hey that rhymes).

```
$ echo /proc/* | sed 's@/proc/[0-9]\+ @@g;s@/proc/@@g'
```

This approach finds all the strings starting with `/proc/` & digits & a space and substitutes them with nothing, effectively deleting them. After that, we do another `sed` command which does the same to the `/proc/` strings, and we're left with just the non-digit starting strings.

#### Multiple columns

For "collating" output into columns, the `paste` command does this fairly easily. Here I'm doing 2 columns, but you can change the `paste` command to generate more or less by adding additional dashes (`-`). The `column -t` at the end forces the output to line up on columns.

```
$ ls /proc | grep -v "^[0-9].*" | paste - - | column -t
```

#### Example

First 5 lines of output thanks to the `head -5`.

```
$ ls /proc | grep -v "^[0-9].*" | paste - - |column -t | head -5
acpi           asound
buddyinfo      bus
cgroups        cmdline
cpuinfo        crypto
devices        diskstats
```

Here's the same thing with 4 columns:

```
$ ls /proc | grep -v "^[0-9].*" | paste - - - - |column -t | head -5
acpi           asound         buddyinfo     bus
cgroups        cmdline        cpuinfo       crypto
devices        diskstats      dma           dri
driver         execdomains    fb            filesystems
fs             interrupts     iomem         ioports
```

**NOTE:** Per @JosephR.'s answer, if you encounter any problems with the above commands that are parsing output from `ls`, you can prefix it with the Bash command, `command`, which will bypass any aliases you may have in place for `ls`.

#### Example

```
$ command ls /proc | grep -v "^[0-9].*" | paste - - - - |column -t | head -5
acpi           asound         buddyinfo     bus
cgroups        cmdline        cpuinfo       crypto
devices        diskstats      dma           dri
driver         execdomains    fb            filesystems
fs             interrupts     iomem         ioports
```

Comment: The last command doesn't work for me. It lists directories that _do_ start with numbers.

Comment: @JosephR. - can you double check? It's working fine for me.

Comment: I got the problem. My `ls` is aliased to `ls --color` which adds non-printing escape sequences to colorize the output, that somehow ended up on `grep`'s radar. `command ls ...` worked. Yet another reason not to parse `ls`.

Comment: @JosephR. - that's your motto by now, which I agree with. But we've all done this in a pinch 8-).

Comment: Agreed :); seems unjustified in this case, though.

Comment: Your first command doesn't work (+1 for the others though). The OP wants those files in /proc` that do not start with a digit but if you use `echo` everything starts with `/proc` so nothing will match `^[0-9]`. Have a look at the output you posted, everything starts with a number. And, in any case, if you use echo directly, everything will be on the same line so `grep` will either match everything or nothing. Having a bad day?:)

Comment: @terdon - not till you pointed that out 8-).

Comment: @terdon - fixed it, liked the other one better 8-). Looked nicer, even though it didn't work.

Comment: @terdon - was distracted putting my 3 kids on the bus BTW.

Comment: Excuses, excuses, always excuses :). Still doesn't work by the way, that prints out all those that _do_ start with numbers.

Comment: @terdon - whoops, got it backwards that he wanted those, fixing now.

Comment: @terdon - ah went back to grep.

Comment: @terdon - put the sed method back in too. Pesky little bugger.

Comment: Ah, finally had your coffee have you? An who're you calling pesky? :)

Comment: @terdon - sed and grep are pesky. You're enjoying this entirely too much 8-)

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
ls /proc | grep -v "^[0-9].*" | perl -pe 's/\n/,/'
```

Answer (score 1):

How about taking advantage of the bash's `IFS`-based word-splitting in conjunction with command substitution (assuming default `IFS`)

```
echo $(ls /proc | grep -v "^[0-9].*")
acpi buddyinfo bus cmdline cpuinfo.....
```

Answer (score 1):

`ls` only displays its output in columns when it's printing to a terminal. When its output is a file or a pipe, `ls` prints one item per line.

You can use the option `-C` to print in columns regardless of the type of output stream, but that will make it impossible (or at least, hard) to filter output with `grep`.

You can tell `ls` to ignore files whose name begins with a digit. This is the simplest way of getting output which is like the output from `ls /proc` only without the process directories.

```
ls -I '[0-9]*'
```

Alternatively, you can specify which entries you want to list.

```
(cd /proc && ls -d [!0-9]*)
```

If you just want the entries and don't care about presentation or colors, use shell wildcards instead of `ls`. The second command is specific to zsh.

```
(cd /proc && echo [!0-9]*)
echo /proc/[^0-9]*(:t)
```